# Quisiera saber el nombre de unas tablas en SAP R/3

Tags: sap

Nunca he usado un ERP y me pidieron que encontrara las tablas equivalentes en SAP R/3, los nombres nada mas, de las tablas **jdt1**, **ojdt** y **oact** de SAP Business One.

Quisiera saber si los nombres son iguales en ambos SAP o si cambian, también quisiera saber los campos, si alguien tiene por fa algun lugar para ver esta info o que me pueda explicar seria genial!!

Answer (score 1):

Sap te da la opción de visualizar los detalles en de cada campo en la erp
Lo que debes hacer es darle a visualizar y en la opción información del sistema debe estar marcada y como vez en la imagen en la parte inferior te dice el nombre de la tabla según el modulo en el que estés

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Listado de tablas SAP B1

Master Files:

OITM = Item Master
OCRD = Customer, Vendor, and Lead Master
CRD1 = Customer Master Address
OCRG = Customer Master Group Code
OHEM = Employee Master
OUSR = SBO Users

Document Files:
ORDR = Sales Order Header
RDR1 = Sales Order Detail (Items)
OINV = Invoice Header
INV1 = Invoice Line Details (Items)

Administration

DunningLetters 
Dunning levels definition 
ODUN

Recipients 
Message recipient list 
AOB1

Messages 
Messages 
OALR

Currencies 
Currency codes 
OCRN

UserPermissionTree 
User authorizations for add-on forms 
OUPT

UserPermissionForms 
User permission forms 
UPT1

Users 
Users of SAP Business One application 
OUSR

UserPermission 
User authorizations 
USR3

AddonChecking(SBO-COMMON Database Only runned this table) 
Overall Addon Path Defining 
SARI

User Queries 
User Queries 
OUQR

Finance

Budget 
Budget management 
OBGT

Budget_Lines 
Budget item details of an account 
BGT1

BudgetDistribution 
Budget distribution methods 
OBGD

BudgetScenarios 
Budget scenarios 
OBGS

ChartOfAccounts 
G/L accounts 
OACT

JournalVouchers 
Journal vouchers 
OBTD

JournalEntries_Lines 
Journal transaction – rows 
JDT1

JournalEntries 
Journal transaction 
OJDT

SalesTaxAuthorities 
Sales tax jurisdictions 
OSTA

SalesTaxAuthoritiesTypes 
Sales tax authority types 
OSTT

SalesTaxCodes 
Inclusive sales tax codes 
OSTC

Marketing Documents and Receipts

(Sales Opportunities, Sales A/R, and Purchasing A/P)
Document_Lines 
Delivery note rows 
DLN1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
Delivery note rows – expenses 
DLN2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
Delivery note – expenses 
DLN3

AdditionalExpenses 
Defines additional expenses 
OEXD

Document_Lines 
Draft – rows 
DRF1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
Draft rows – expenses 
DRF2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
Draft – expenses 
DRF3

Document_Lines 
Invoice – rows 
INV1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
Invoice rows – expenses 
INV2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
Invoice – expenses 
INV3

Document (oDeliveryNote) 
Delivery – header 
ODLN

Documents 
Drafts – header 
ODRF

Documents (oInvoice) 
Invoice – header 
OINV

Document (oPurchaseInvoices) 
AP invoice – header 
OPCH

Document (oPurchaseDeliveryNotes) 
Goods receipt purchase order – header 
OPDN

Document (oPurchaseOrders) 
Purchase order – header 
OPOR

Document (oQuotation) 
Quotation – header 
OQUT

Document (oReturn) 
Returns – header 
ORDN

Document (oOrder) 
Order – header 
ORDR

Document (oCreditNote) 
AR credit memo – header 
ORIN

Document (oPurchaseCreditNotes) 
AP credit memo – header 
ORPC

Document (oPurchaseReturns) 
Goods return – header 
ORPD

Document_Lines 
AP invoice – rows 
PCH1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
AP invoice rows – expenses 
PCH2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
AP invoice – expenses 
PCH3

Document_Lines 
Goods receipt purchase order – row 
PDN1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
Goods receipt purchase order rows – expenses 
PDN2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
Goods receipt purchase order – expenses 
PDN3

Document_Lines 
Purchase order – rows 
POR1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
Purchase order rows – expenses 
POR2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
Purchase order – expenses 
POR3

Document_Lines 
Quotation – rows 
QUT1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
Quotation rows – expenses 
QUT2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
Quotation – expenses 
QUT3

Document_Lines 
Returns – rows 
RDN1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
Return rows – expenses 
RDN2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
Returns – expenses 
RDN3

Document_Lines 
Order – rows 
RDR1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
Order rows – expenses 
RDR2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
Order – expenses 
RDR3

Document_Lines 
Credit memo – rows 
RIN1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
Credit memo rows -Expenses 
RIN2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
Credit memo – expenses 
RIN3

Document_Lines 
AP credit memo – rows 
RPC1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
AP credit memo rows – expenses 
RPC2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
AP credit memo – expenses 
RPC3

Document_Lines 
Goods return – rows 
RPD1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
Goods return rows – expenses 
RPD2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
Goods return – expenses 
RPD3

BatchNumbers 
Batch number for item 
OIBT

Industries 
Industries list for sales opportunities 
OOND

Relationships 
Relationships for sales opportunities 
OORL

SerialNumbers 
Serial numbers for items 
OSRI

WithholdingTaxData 
Withholding tax data 
INV5

TaxInvoices (botit_Invoice) 
Master header data of a tax invoice of sales document 
OTSI

TaxInvoice_Lines (botit_Invoice) 
Tax invoice of sales document – rows 
TSI1

TaxInvoices (botit_Payment) 
Master header data of a tax invoice of purchase document 
OTPI

TaxInvoice_Lines (botit_Payment) 
Tax invoice of purchase document – rows 
TPI1

TaxInvoices (botit_JournalEntry) 
Master header data of a tax invoice of journal entry document 
OTXD 
TaxInvoice_Lines (botit_JournalEntry) 
Tax invoice of journal entry document – rows 
TXD1

Business Partners

ActivityLocations 
Business partner activity locations 
OCLO

ActivityStatus 
Statuses for Task type activities 
OCLA

ActivityTypes 
Business partner activity types 
OCLT

AlternateCatNum 
Customer or vendor catalog number 
OSCN

BusinessPartners 
Business partners 
OCRD

BPAddresses 
Business partner addresses 
CRD1

BPPaymentMethods 
Business partner payment methods 
CRD2

BPAccountReceivablePayble 
Business partner account receivable payable 
CRD3

BPWithholdingTax 
Business partner withholding tax 
CRD4

BPPaymentDates 
Business partners payment dates 
CRD5

BPBankAccounts 
Business partners bank accounts 
OCRB

Contacts 
Contact customers and vendors 
OCLG

ContactEmployees 
Contact persons 
OCPR

SalesOpportunities 
Sales opportunities 
OOPR

SalesOpportunitiesLines 
Sales opportunity – rows 
OPR1

SalesOpportunitiesPartners 
Sales opportunity partners 
OPR2

SalesOpportunitiesCompetition 
Sales opportunity competition 
OPR3

SalesOpportunitiesInterests 
Sales opportunity interests range 
OPR4

SalesOpportunitiesReasons 
Sales opportunity failure reasons 
OPR5

Territories 
Territory segmentations 
OTER

Inventory and Production

Document_Lines 
Goods issue – rows 
IGE1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
Goods issue rows – expenses 
IGE2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
Goods issue – expenses 
IGE3

Document_Lines 
Goods receipt – rows 
IGN1

Document_LinesAdditionalExpenses 
Goods receipt rows – expenses 
IGN2

DocumentsAdditionalExpenses 
Goods receipt – expenses 
IGN3

Document (oInvetoryGenExit) 
Goods issue 
OIGE

Document (oInvetoryGenEntry) 
Goods receipt 
OIGN

StockTransfer 
Stock transfers 
OWTR

StockTransfer_Lines 
Stock transfers – rows 
WTR1

ProductTrees_Lines 
Product tree – child 
ITT1

ProductTrees 
Product tree 
OITT

WorkOrders 
Work instructions 
OWKO

WorkOrder_Lines 
Work instructions – rows 
WKO1

Items_Prices 
Items – prices 
ITM1

Items 
Items 
OITM

ItemWarehouseInfo 
Items – warehouse 
OITW

ItemGroups 
Item groups definition 
OITB

MaterialRevaluation 
Stock revaluation 
OMRV

MaterialRevaluation_Lines 
Stock revaluation – rows 
MRV1

PackagesTypes 
Package types for deliveries 
OPKG

PriceLists 
Price lists management 
OPLN

StockTaking 
Items – warehouse 
OITW

SpecialPrices 
Special prices 
OSPP

SpecialPricesDataAreas 
Special prices for specified periods 
SPP1

SpecialPricesQuantityAreas 
Special prices for specified quantities 
SPP2

Warehouses 
Warehouses definition 
OWHS 
MRP

SalesForecast 
Sales forecast 
OFCT

SalesForecast_Lines 
Sales forecast – rows 
FCT1

Banking

Payments 
Receipt 
ORCT

Payments 
Vendor payment 
OVPM

Payments_Checks 
Receipt – checks 
RCT1

Payments_Invoices 
Receipt – invoices 
RCT2

Payments_CreditCards 
Receipt – credit vouchers 
RCT3

Payments_Accounts 
Receipt – account list 
RCT4

Payments_Checks 
Payments – check rows 
VPM1

Payments_Invoices 
Payments – invoices 
VPM2

Payments_CreditCards 
Payments – credit memos 
VPM3

Payments_Accounts 
Payments – list of accounts 
VPM4

ChecksforPaymentLines 
Checks for payment – rows 
CHO1

BankPages 
External bank statement 
OBNK

ChecksforPayment 
Check for payment 
OCHO

PaymentTermsTypes 
Payment term types 
OCTG

PaymentRunExport 
Payment results table 
OPEX

PaymentRunExport_Lines 
Payment results table – rows 
PEX1

BillOfExchange 
Bill of exchange table 
OBOE

BillOfExchangeTransaction 
Bill of exchange transactions table 
OBOT

BillOfExchangeTransaction_Lines 
Bill of exchange transactions table – rows 
BOT1

Service

ContractTemplates 
Contract template (CRM) 
OCTT

CustomerEquipmentCards 
Customer equipment card 
OINS

KnowledgeBaseSolutions 
Knowledge base solution 
OSLT

Queue 
Queues list for assigning to a service calls 
OQUE

QueueMembers 
Queue member users 
QUE1

ServiceContracts 
Service contract 
OCTR

ServiceContracts_Lines 
Service contract – rows 
CTR1

ServiceCalls 
Service call 
OSCL

ServiceCallActivities 
Service call activities 
OCLG

ServiceCallInventoryExpenses 
Service call inventory expenses 
INV1

Human Resources

EmployeesInfo 
Employees information 
OHEM

EmployeeAbsenceInfo 
Employee absence information 
HEM1

EmployeeEducationInfo 
Employee education 
HEM2

EmployeeReviewsInfo 
Employee reviews 
HEM3

EmployeePrevEmpoymentInfo 
Employee previous employment information 
HEM4

EmployeeRolesInfo 
Employee rolls information 
HEM6

Teams 
List of teams 
OHTM

TeamMembers 
Employee membership role in a team 
HTM1